# In Hadoop where does the framework save the output of the Map task in a normal Map-Reduce Application?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, cloudera

I am trying to find out where does the output of a Map task is saved to disk before it can be used by a Reduce task.

**Note:** - version used is Hadoop 0.20.204 with the new API

For example, when overwriting the map method in the Map class:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
    }

    // code that starts a new Job.

}
```

I am interested to find out where does context.write() ends up writing the data. So far i've ran into the:

```
FileOutputFormat.getWorkOutputPath(context);
```

Which gives me the following location on hdfs:

```
hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/outputs/1/_temporary/_attempt_201112221334_0001_m_000000_0
```

When i try to use it as input for another job it gives me the following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/outputs/1/_temporary/_attempt_201112221334_0001_m_000000_0
```

**Note:** the job is started in the Mapper, so technically, the temporary folder where the Mapper task is writing it's output exists when the new job begins. Then again, it still says that the input path does not exist.

Any ideas to where the temporary output is written to? Or maybe what is the location where i can find the output of a Map task during a job that has both a Map and a Reduce stage?

Comment: BTW, looks like FileOutputhFormat#getWorkOutputPath gives the location of the temporary output folder for the job and not for the map task as per the api documentation. `When i try to use it as input for another job it gives me the following error:` - usually temporary files are deleted once the job is completed or else the node would get full easily.

Comment: OK, fair point, but i am starting the job while the other job is executing. I'm doing nested map reduce. So, the outerjob is busy-waiting while the inner job is executing, so there shouldn't be any deletion of temporary files.

Comment: But ok, fair enough things get deleted, which means they were somewhere before they were deleted. I need to find out where that is. :D

Comment: It's not a good practice to depend on the temporary files, since they can be changed across releases without changing the API.

Comment: I agree with you, but then again, i need the output and i don't know how to get it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I've figured out what is really going on.

The output of the mapper is buffered until it gets to about 80% of its size, and at that point it begins to dump the result to its local disk and continues to admit items into the buffer.

I wanted to get the intermediate output of the mapper and use it as input for another job, while the mapper was still running. It turns out that this is not possible without heavily modifying the hadoop 0.20.204 deployment. The way the system works is even after all the things that are specified in the map context:

```
map .... {
  setup(context)
  .
  .
  cleanup(context)
}
```

and the cleanup is called, there is still no dumping to the temporary folder.

After, the whole Map computation everything eventually gets merged and dumped to disk and becomes the input for the Shuffling and Sorting stages that precede the Reducer.

So far from all I've read and looked at, the temporary folder where the output should be eventually, is the one that I was guessing beforehand.

```
FileOutputFormat.getWorkOutputPath(context)
```

I managed to the what I wanted to do in a different way. Anyway
any questions there might be about this, let me know.

Answer (score 6):

Map reduce framework will store intermediate output into local disk rather than HDFS as this would cause unnecessarily replication of files.

Answer (score 2):

Task tracker starts a separate JVM process for every Map or Reduce task.

Mapper output (intermediate data) is written to the Local file system (NOT HDFS) of each mapper slave node. Once data transferred to Reducer, We won’t be able to access these temporary files.

If you what to see your Mapper output, I suggest using `IdentityReducer`?