# Where is data kept after Map/Combine and before Reduce stage in Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

In Spark, we can keep the data in-memory whenever we want, but I was wondering where the data is kept between the Map and Reduce stages in Hadoop MapReduce. Is it kept in HDFS, disk or RAM? I mean, when the data is being shuffled (After Map/Combiner and before Reduce, that is), where is it kept?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Hadoop where does the framework save the output of the Map task in a normal Map-Reduce Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603435/in-hadoop-where-does-the-framework-save-the-output-of-the-map-task-in-a-normal-m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge in Hadoop Mapreduce.

1) Map tasks outputs are written to the local disk.(After Map/Combiner and before Reduce task)

2) Reducer task output are written in HDFS.

If Mapreduce job has only Mapper task output is written in HDFS

Hope this Helps!!!...

Comment: In local disk or the HDFS?

Comment: Local disk (After Map/Combiner and before Reduce task) you can find few Mapreduce example in http://ybhavesh.blogspot.in/2015/12/poc-sensex-log-data-processing-pdf-file.html

Answer (score 0):

In regular Hadoop MapReduce the Job output data between each step has to be stored in the distributed file system (HDFS) before the next step can begin. So reducers has to fetch data from there and this adds disk/cluster-overhead time.

Overhead becomes quite large when to perform high-complexity operations you need to schedule different Map/Reduce Jobs sequentially (in Hadoop), where each one of them will store and then retrieve data in HDFS.

Spark improves drastically performance keeping those partial results in memory when possible.

Answer (score 0):

All the intermediate data will be stored in HDFS disk. Since All the map/reduce operations are not done in single node. So for other nodes easy data access(Processed data), All the interim data will be stored in HDFS disk.

Only the data which is needed for operation will be taken in to the memory.